# How to seperate video Url from image when you upload to firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have an application which users can upload multiply files only images and videos and store them to Firebase Storage...

I get the URL files and store to them in array. I fetch those URL to Network Image but I can display the video URL which is part of what the user upload....

please how can I seperate the url and use another widget to display the url.....

HERE IS MY CODE

```
ListView.builder(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: userprofile.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            print(userprofile.length);
            return (index == 0)
                ? Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    width: 130,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))),
                    child: Stack(
                      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                      children: [
                        GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () async {
                            //TODO:i want to able to click and upload
                            if (await uploadMultipleImages()) {
                              print('Uploaded successfully..............');
                            }
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                            width: 130,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border.all(
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: NetworkImage(
                                      "${useinformation['profilePictureUrl'].toString()}"),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                ),
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                          bottom: 60,
                          left: 45,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () async {
                              //TODO: i want to able to click and upload
                              if (await uploadMultipleImages()) {
                                print('Uploaded successfully..............');
                              }
                            },
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: themeProvider
                                  .getThemeColor()
                                  .withOpacity(0.3),
                              radius: 20,
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.add,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ))
```

///here is the place that will show the list of url from the list, but the problem is if one of the url is video it will not  show so how can i seperate if the url is video so that i can use anothe widget to show the it

```
: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    width: 130,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                        ),
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(userprofile[index]),
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30))),
                  );
          }),
```

THE ERROR AFTER FETCH PART OF THE URL AND ONE OF THE URL IS VIDEO URL

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmNYg.png)
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your URL and compare the extension.

```
String _extension = _someURL.split(".").last.split("?").first.toLowerCase();
```

then use this extension to classify video and image.

```
child: _extension == "jpg" || _extension == "jpeg" ? 
                                    Image.Network(_someURL) : VideoPlayer(_someURL)
```

Comment: Class 'String' has no instance method 'call'.
Receiver: "jpg?alt=media&token=79f217bd-aeb3-4a95-ace6-05a34749d5fd"
Tried calling: call()

Comment: this is what i am getting